# Can there be more than one android:id/list?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

If the ListViews are in separate activities, can there be more than one ListView id'ed as "@android:id/list"?

Comment: You should try before asking but the answer is yes

Comment: But the best way is not to use ListActivities nor ListFragments at all. Simply use **ListViews**. You can have an indefinite number in the same Activity or Fragment.

Comment: @DerGolem why is that the best way?

Comment: As I said: `Simply use ListViews. You can have an indefinite number in the same Activity or Fragment.`

Comment: @DerGolem but OP isn't asking about in the same activity/fragment. If you only need one, why is it the best way?

Comment: ... and reinvent the wheel for stuff like empty data set, loading progress, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! For different activities ID will not be conflicted.
Even in **android studio** you can navigate to all the list items of a same ID from a single JAVA file by pressing `Ctrl + hover` over the id.